# ¿Como poner un TextureRegion[] en un TileMap en libGDX?

Tags: libgdx

Estoy creando un juego y para el personaje utilicé un array de TextureRegion, con el fin de animar el movimiento al andar. Tengo todo hecho, salvo que al dibujar el personaje con el *SpriteBatch*. Cuando paso por detrás de un objeto especificado en una capa aparte del *TileMap*, el personaje pasa por delante.

Lo entendereis con esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabría como manejarlo? O más bien, en lugar de utilizar un `TextureRegion[]` utilizando un *Sprite* y, si es el caso, ¿como Animar dicho *Sprite* con `TextureRegion[]`? Gracias!

**EDICION:**

Añado aquí el trozo de código aún sin terminar del todo,falta dar los retoques, pero principalmente quiero hacer que funcione para centrarme luego en la lógica y en los bugs.

**CLASE PERSONAJE:**

```
public TextureRegion[] getPersonaje(String personaje, int direccion) {
    Texture p = new Texture(personaje + ".png");

    region[0] = new TextureRegion(p, 0, ALTO_PERSONAJE * direccion, ANCHO_PERSONAJE, ALTO_PERSONAJE);
    region[1] = new TextureRegion(p, ANCHO_PERSONAJE, ALTO_PERSONAJE * direccion, ANCHO_PERSONAJE, ALTO_PERSONAJE);
    region[2] = new TextureRegion(p, ANCHO_PERSONAJE * 2, ALTO_PERSONAJE * direccion, ANCHO_PERSONAJE, ALTO_PERSONAJE);
    region[3] = new TextureRegion(p, ANCHO_PERSONAJE * 3, ALTO_PERSONAJE * direccion, ANCHO_PERSONAJE, ALTO_PERSONAJE);

    return region;
}
```

**CLASE LOGICA:**

```
public void mover(Personaje p, SpriteBatch batch, String nombre_personaje, int dir, boolean moviendose, boolean corriendo) {
    //boolean colision = comprobarColision(dir, x, y);
    if (corriendo) {
        velocidad = 3;
    } else {
        velocidad = 1;
    }


    TextureRegion[] personaje = p.getPersonaje(nombre_personaje, dir);

    Animation animacion = new Animation(1 / 5f, personaje);

    if (moviendose /*&& !colision*/) {
        if (dir == DIR_DERECHA) {
            x += velocidad;
        } else if (dir == DIR_ARRIBA) {
            y += velocidad;
        } else if (dir == DIR_IZQUIERDA) {
            x -= velocidad;
        } else {
            y -= velocidad;
        }

        delta += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        batch.draw(animacion.getKeyFrame(delta, true), x, y);
    } else
        batch.draw(personaje[0], x, y);
}
```

**CLASE PRINCIPAL:**

```
@Override
public void create() {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camara = new OrthographicCamera();
    camara.setToOrtho(false, w, h);
    camara.update();

    mapa = new TmxMapLoader().load("mapa.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(mapa);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camara.combined);

    l = new Logica();
    p = new Personaje();
 }

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camara.update();
    renderer.setView(camara);
    renderer.render();

    batch.begin();
    l.mover(p, batch, "Prota", direccion, pulsado, turbo);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: ¿Has ordenado el modo en que se hace el render del mapa? Mira la [documentación](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps) para saber cómo tener más control del render. La clase `Sprite` no te va a arreglar nada, es sólo una clase que une texturas con posición, rotación, etc... La única forma de arreglar eso es personalizando tu render. Yo lo hago ordenando los objetos por la coordenada `y`. Si me pones tu código de renderizado del mapa podría echarte una mano.

Comment: Si te fijas el problema esta que renderizas todo el mapa y luego renderizas el personaje. Así siempre va a estar tu personaje encima de todo. Para cambiar eso debes pintar primero el suelo y luego ordenar los objetos y tu personaje pero ordenados en el orden inverso a como se tienen que ver.

Comment: He estado revisando el resto del código que has puesto y tienes fallos muy gordos. El más grande está en tu método `mover(...)`. Piensa que a ese método lo vas a llamar probablemente 60 veces cada segundo y en cada llamada estás mapeando la textura (de lo más pesado que hay) y creando una animación que nunca avanzará porque siempre empieza de cero. Te sugiero que revises bien la wiki de libgdx para saber cómo debes hacer las cosas. Si necesitas ayuda puedes contactar conmigo si miras mi perfil.

Comment: Si, eso ya lo se, hice todo este código a prisa sin la parte de análisis ni nada, solo con el fin de que funcione para luego centrarme en optimizarlo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido mucho. Respecto a la animación, si funciona, el problema es que la creo de cada vez, pero funcionar funciona. Lo mismo con el personaje, lo obtengo de cada vez que llamo al método mover(...), pero ya había reparado en eso, lo hice, como ya te digo, por ver que funcione para optimizarlo posteriormente. De hecho este código fue hecho en 1 tarde. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Utilices TextureRegion o Sprite el orden en el que si dibujan es segun lo pongas. Si lo que quieres es dibujar el personaje detrás de los objetos altos, podrías hacer un nuevo Layer en TiledMap y colocar estos objetos "altos".

Al momento de hacer render, digamos que tienes un total de 3 layers {0,1,2} y que el 1(en el array) es el de los objetos altos.

```
//Todos los layers excepto el de los objetos 
private int[] layers = {0,2};
//El layer de los objetos altos
private int[] objetosAltosLayer = {1};
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camara.update();
    renderer.setView(camara);

    //aqui dibujamos todos los layers excepto el de los objetos altos
    renderer.render(layers); 

    //dibujas el personaje
    batch.begin();
    l.mover(p, batch, "Prota", direccion, pulsado, turbo);
    batch.end();

    //dibujas los objetos altos
    renderer.render(objetosAltosLayer);
}
```

Claro que esta no es la solución final por que en algunas ocasiones queras dibujar el personaje después de los objetos altos... aquí te dejo una imagen para que veas la lógica...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]